# Prove that a subset of an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Find a subset $H$ of $A$, and prove that it is countable.

Since I do not know what $A$ is, to form a subset of it, I am going to define a set $H$ that is comprised of $a_{q,n}$, which are elements of the intersection of $A$ and $I_{q,n}$, where for each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $I_{q,n} = (q-\frac{1}{n}, q+\frac{1}{n})$. If the intersection turns up empty, let $a_{q,n}$ go undefined. So, in other words, $H=\{ a_{q,n} : q \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

$H$ is certainly a subset of $A$, but how do I show that $H$ is countable? I think I need to find an injective function $f:H -> \mathbb{Q} cross \mathbb{N} $, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: The fact that $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ is irrelevant. The proof is the same for an arbitrary infinite set.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it would be important inasmuch as you know that A could contain all manner of different objects, such as irrationals.

Comment: No, the proof is the same proof for an arbitrary set which contains all manner of different objects, like an assortment of sets, numbers, functions, vector spaces, and more sets.

Comment: Ah. Well, what has me puzzled about this one is all the moving parts, so-to-speak. We have $a_{q,n}$, which may or may not be empty, or selected more than once. We have $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. It's all very confusing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, would you give some guidance on how to prove that H is countable?

Comment: The wording of this question is confusing. It sounds like it is making the incorrect claim that if $H$ is a subset of an infinite set, then $H$ must be countable (first find the subset $H$, then prove it is countable). All commenters have implicitly addressed the modified (true) claim: "Every infinite set has a countably infinite subset."

Answer (score 1):

SKETCH: As Asaf said, the fact that you’re working in $\Bbb R$ is irrelevant; just let $A$ be any infinite set. Construct $H$ recursively, one point at a time. The fact that $A$ is infinite means that at every stage, when you’ve picked only the first $n$ points, say, there’s sure to be a point left to choose. Try to write it up yourself. If you get stuck, I’ve left a spoiler-protected write-up below; mouse-over to see it.

> Let $a_0\in A$ be arbitrary. Since $A$ is infinite, $A\setminus\{a_0\}\ne\varnothing$, so we may choose any $a_1\in A\setminus\{a_0\}$. In general suppose that $n\in\Bbb N$, and we have already chosen distinct elements $a_k\in A$ for $k<n$; $A$ is infinite, so $A\setminus\{a_k:k<n\}\ne\varnothing$, and we may choose $a_n\in A\setminus\{a_k:k<n\}$. In the end let $H=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. By construction the map $\Bbb N\to H:n\mapsto a_n$ is a bijection.

Comment: Surprisingly, this recursive construction of $H$ is rather intuitive. But $H$ seems to be a 'copy' of A, is that right? Here is another question, @BrianM.Scott: is this subset of H dense in A since the closure of H contains A?

Comment: @Brian: $H$ needn’t even have the same cardinality as $A$: $H$ is countably infinite, while $A$ can be uncountable. None of this has anything to do with topology: the fact is simply that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset. In the specific case of your problem setting take $A$ to be all of $\Bbb R$; the construction could produce any countably infinite subset of $\Bbb R$, since nothing in it controls how the points are chosen (other than to make them distinct). You might end up with the dense subset $\Bbb Q$, but you might end up with $\Bbb Z$, which has no limit points at all.

Comment: I see, so every infinite set has a countable infinite subset - that is a helpful theorem! I ask because the next part of the question asks if A is separable. Can I the recursively-defined H and show it's dense in A? That would be sufficient to show that A is separable.

Comment: @Brian: That construction won’t guarantee that $H$ is dense in $A$, and I don’t really see why the two questions are combined. The easiest way to show that $A$ is separable is to use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is second countable: the countable family of open intervals with rational endpoints is a base for $\Bbb R$. Their intersections with $A$ therefore form a base for the topology on $A$. What happens if you pick one point from each of the non-empty intersections?

Comment: Now, I think you can see why I defined the set H the way I did in my question - I was thinking ahead and trying to tackle two problems at once! The problem, though, is trying to prove that my set H is countable and dense, and though I have difficulty with proving both, I thought I would tackle countability first!

Comment: How about this. Let f be mapping from D to Q x N such that a_q,n is mapped to (q,n). Does that work?